# Can echo -e be used with in a script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, raspbian

We would like this `echo` command to be run within a script but are having issues.

```
/bin/echo -e 'connect XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX \n quit \n' | bluetoothctl
```

How can I run this command in a bash script?

Comment: What are these *issues*? A more portable version would be `printf 'connect XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX \n quit \n' | bluetoothctl`

Comment: Thanks Socowi my peer created the script using printf and we were not getting errors he is now testing it out. - Sadly we are both Windows guys so we are slowly getting to learn linux

Comment: Try to avoid `-e`; it may or may not be supported by your implementation of `echo`. It enables behavior that the POSIX standard specifies should be enabled be default, and conforming implementations will treat it as a literal string to be output, not an option.

Comment: @Mockatoy `echo -e` is fine in bash. The problem was most likely that you were using `sh` instead. Maybe you ran it as `sh file` or used `#!/bin/sh` as the shebang. Avoid that, it's the equivalent of trying to compile C++ with a C compiler.

Comment: @thatotherguy Yes that was the issue we found, he went a head and used printf and its working perfectly. thanks!

Comment: *usually* fine in bash; `shopt -s xpg_echo` and `set -o posix` -- or have those settings enabled via either environment variables or compile-time flags -- and `echo -e` starts printing `-e` even there.

Answer (score 2):

`printf` is your best option, however, for the case you have this will also work

```
echo 'connect XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX 
 quit 
' | bluetoothctl
```

Answer (score 1):

My peer created the following

```
#!/bin/bash
printf 'connect C4:7D:CC:3D:A7:A3 \n quit \n' | bluetoothctl
```

so far he said its working thanks everyone!

Comment: Consider also `printf '%s\n' 'connect C4:7D:CC:3D:A7:A3' quit | bluetoothctl`; that way your constant strings (the `connect` and `quit` arguments to `printf` are separated from the format string, so `%`s and backslashes aren't special within them.

Comment: ...or `bluetoothctl <<EOF`, and then `connect ...` and `quit` on separate lines, followed by a third line containing only `EOF`.